# Is it possible to validate my JavaScript library using a public/private key signing method?

Tags: javascript, browser

I am dynamically loading my JavaScript as a "plugin" on a third party's page and would like to verify that it's coming from me.

I can use the content SRI, however I update the library frequently and need it to be dynamically loaded.

Below is an example of what I'd like to see. Is there a way I can achieve this?

```js
const publickey = '...my-key...'

const response = await fetch('https://example.com/my-library.js')
const sig = response.headers.get('X-Signature')
const text = await response.text()

try {
   validate(text, sig, publicKey)
   const s = document.createElement('script')
   s.innerHTML = text
   document.head.appendChild(s)
} catch(err) {
   console.error("")
}
```

Comment: Modern browsers have the `SubtleCrypto` interface for performing cryptographic primitives: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto

Comment: I would still have to manually verify the payload against the signature right? Meaning I would violate `inline-script` CSP (in the above example)

Comment: ...you haven't mentioned having a CSP at all.

Comment: That's fair, I just realised after I posted the question. Will update the original post to reflect. The `SubtleCrypto` methods are very useful as a starting point

Comment: Use `fetch` with [`arrayBuffer()`][https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/arrayBuffer] to load the response into an `ArrayBuffer` object **without going through text encoding** (which `.text()` will do) to preserve the exact octet values of the response. Then use it with [`SubtleCrypto.verify`][https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/verify].

Comment: Added this question to cover the CSP concern: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63107413/is-it-possible-to-cryptographically-verify-my-javascript-without-violating-stric?noredirect=1#comment111594682_63107413